# Xcode 13 failing building with "entry point (_main) undefined. for architecture arm64"

Tags: ios, xcode, sdl, sdl-2

I am trying to build a SDL (libsdl.org) iOS app I havent built for a few years and I am having some problem.
Have the following settings:
[image]
The error I get is:

**ld:** warning: ignoring file /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/APPNAME-acpmwonxbccjqtaxaenqojducdea/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libAPPNAME2.a, building for iOS Simulator-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for iOS Simulator-x86_64

**ld:** entry point (_main) undefined. for architecture arm64

I am not sure if the first warning is related to the error.
I have a target for an archive with SDL source files.

If I add arm64 to "Excluded Architectures" (based on other stackoverflow answers) it builds but I get a "Executable Not Found" error message.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing:
"VALID_ARCHS[sdk=*]" = "arm64 armv7 armv7s";
from project.pbxproj solved the problem

Comment: where is the VALID_ARCHS? Thank you for your response.

Comment: It was in the "project-name".pbxproj file

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem. In my case there was no @main annotation in class AppDelegate.