# Unable to build for simulators while working for actual device

Tags: swift, xcode

While facing no issue with actual iPhone device, my project does not build for simulators. I get this error (which occurres for many fies):

`ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/stephanedeluca/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AladdinWorkspace-afneoinpxpyfmofvnattjgylgxgo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleDataTransport.o, building for iOS Simulator-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-x86_64`

Which sounds like mixing ARM and 86 architectures.

My `VALID_ARCHS` is set to `arm64 arm64e armv7 armv7s i386`

I tried to remove VALID_ARCHS value as stated in the following answer without success:
[Xcode 13 failing building with "entry point (_main) undefined. for architecture arm64"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71402454/xcode-13-failing-building-with-entry-point-main-undefined-for-architecture)

I also tried to delete the DerivedData folder without success either.

[UPDATE] I forgot to mention that there is no more PODs in my workspace as I replaced them by the corresponding g Swift packages.

Any idea?

Comment: The problem seems to be in GoogleDataTransport. Have you tried updating your pods?

Comment: There is no PODs anymore as I replaced by the corresponding swift packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: for some reasons, the architecture for macOS being ˋi386ˋ was not longer right, as I had to change it for `x86_64`.

Finally, my valid architectures are now:
`arm64 arm64e armv7 armv7s x86_64`